# AngularJS invoking function whose name is constructed as a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a situation in which there are main functions named as:

```
Add_<Element_Type>_Page()
```

where `Element_Type` is received as a parameter.

I can see two options to handle the invocation of the correct function:

1. Write a relatively long `switch` construct covering all possible values of `Element_Type`, or
2. Use some existing mechanism/trick (I'm not aware of) through which I can build a string using the received `Element_Type` and invoke a function whose name is contained in that string.

Needless to say, all the functions that can be invoked this way have exactly the same signature as far as parameters is concerned.

Obviously, Option 2 would be the best (easy to maintain and very general as no changes are needed whenever a new type of pages is added).

Is this possible to achieve within AngularJS framework?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are those function written in controller using `$scope` or `vm/ctrl` ?

Comment: Crazy approach, are those functions autogenerated? Please show some code. What should happend in `Add_<Element_Type>_Page()` and where is `Element_Type` needed in those function?

Comment: @tanmay, not sure I follow you, but I think you are referring to Angular 2 while I'm using AngularJS (i.e. 1).

Comment: @FDavidov no it's Angular1 only. I'm asking where are your functions placed? Controller? Service?

Comment: @Iin, not sure why "crazy". The functions are NOT generated automatically (though I wish I could...). They are all hardcoded. The only thing I'm looking for is how to call them without the need of a `switch` construct.

Comment: @tanmay, same controller and their invocation.

Comment: @FDavidov ok, are those functions binded to an object or are they just stand alone function inside the controller?

Comment: @FDavidov yes, so as per my answer below, you can access them, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do that using the `[...]` notation instead of `.`

Like this,

```
$scope["Add_" + Element_Type + "_Page"]()
```

will call `$scope.Add_test_Page()` assuming `Element_Type` would be `test`

or  if using `controllerAs` syntax,

```
vm["Add_" + Element_Type + "_Page"]()
```

where `Element_Type` is a received parameter as you mentioned.

If you want to use it inside HTML, you can have a reference to your `Element_Type` in `$scope`/`vm` (whichever way you are using) and access it.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted your answer, but the first suggestion (using `[...]`) works like a charm. Than you!!!! (marked as THE ANSWER of course).

Comment: @FDavidov yeah it's fine. glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Create an attribute with name func-name and pass your dynamic string value which is your function name to that attribute and within your directive you can do something like this.

```
scope: {
 funcName: '@'
},
controller: function() {
 $scope[$scope.funcName]();
}
```